# Angularjs Dynamic scope not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

hi i'm trying to create $scope dynamically and set it true on click to show some details inside ng-repeat  but it doesn't seem to work ,Here is the plunk [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/F1z4Yp7u9Xw17QkA18A4?p=preview)

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.details=[{
 cid:100,
  foo:'first component'
  },

 {
   cid:101,
 foo:'second component'
  },{
   cid:102,
    foo:'third component'
    }];
 $scope.showGraph=function(serverid){
  console.log(serverid);
   if ($scope[serverid] === undefined) {

     $scope[serverid] = true;
     console.log($scope[serverid]);
    } else {
    $scope[serverid] = true;
     }
      };
   });
```

thanks for your help.Any other suggestions to achieve this is also welcomed.

Comment: Your `ng-if` shows fundamental javascript misunderstanding of dynamic variable names ... String + variable returns string not  variable

Answer (score 3):

Currently you are generating some variable name by dynamically passing serverid parameter to it(single scope variable is taking responsibility of all details collection). And the main issue was how you were trying to retrieve variable value from scope isn't correct syntax(`ng-if` directive expression trying to concatenate strings).

The simplest way to achieve this would be, have a flag `showGraph` on each element of details collection. Then on click just toggle `showGraph` flag

```
  <ul ng-repeat='detail in details'>
    <li><p>{{detail.foo}} <a href="#" ng-click='detail.showGraph =!detail.showGraph'>show graph</a>
    </p>
    <div ng-if='detail.showGraph'>
      show graph here
    </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

[Forked Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/MCeLyVgaqKklfP0LV1o8?p=preview)

Comment: my app is different from that plunker.i'm getting a response from api.